# MS Access: No value given for one or more required parameters

Tags: ms-access, vbscript, asp-classic

I'm trying to run the following query to an MS Access database (from an .asp page) :

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, emp_id FROM employees ORDER BY firstname
```

However, I get an error saying

```
No value given for one or more required parameters.
```

Now, the query runs fine if I exclude the "emp_id" (primary key) field. I have made sure that the field exists and that there are no typos in the query.

If I run the query through the MS Access GUI, there's a pop-up asking me to enter a "parameter value" for the emp_id field. Could this be why it won't work, and why does it happen?

Getting the employees from the db:

```
Function GetEmployees()

    Dim employeesRS, sqlGetEmployees, employeesList, e

    Set employeesList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    sqlGetEmployees = "SELECT firstname, lastname, emp_id FROM employees ORDER BY firstname"

    Set employeesRS = db.connTb.execute(sqlGetEmployees) 'Custom class to simplify db-querying

    While Not employeesRS.EOF

        Set e = new Employee

        e.Firstname = employeesRS("firstname")
        e.Lastname = employeesRS("lastname")
        e.Id = employeesRS("emp_id")

        employeesList.Add(e)

        employeesRS.MoveNext
    Wend

    employeesRS.Close

    Set GetEmployees = employeesList

End Function
```

Screenshot of table structure: (As you probably noticed, I translated the table and code in my post, to make it more readable . The relationship between code/table fields is identical though. )

[image]

Comment: Can you give us your ASP code, as well, please?  And is employees only a table or is it a query in the database?

Comment: updated the question with code. Employees is only a table

Comment: When you run it throuhg MSAccess and you get a prompt for argument, there is no field called emp_id in the table. Make sure that it really is emp_id and not empid or something else

Comment: I have checked it over and over again. The field exists :/

Comment: Like @SearchAndResQ has said when you run it in Access it isn't recognising `emp_id` as a table field and so assumes it's a input parameter and asks for a value. Can you show the table structure (`employees`), maybe a screenshot of the design view in Access?

Comment: Looking at  the screenshot you posted, Is `Ansattnr` an alias or the name of the column in the table? It would have been better if you had posted the tables design view as screenshot not the table contents.

Comment: @Lankymart You are right. I figured it out right before I saw your response. Ansattnr is indeed an alias, I didn't know you could do that :S

Comment: @mskutle No problem glad that mystery is solved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved:

The query result view in MS Access showed the field name to be "emp_id", but the actual name was "employee_id".

The program using the database used to be an Access-forms application and therefore had different names on the columns in the query result view than the actual names (for some reason, I don't know why that sounded like a good idea)